# Is there a way to link non-https resources into a github pages site?

Tags: https, github-pages

So I get the following error in Chrome console:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://your-username.github.io/' was
>   loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet
>   'http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.6.0/pure-min.css'. This request has
>   been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Basically the yahoo pure library is being served over HTTP.  Is the only solution simply to download it and link to it in a "relative directory" format from my index.html page (e.g., "./pure-min.css")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested [in this issue](https://github.com/sugarcrm/sugarcrm_dev/issues/212#issuecomment-55142308), try instead

> replacing all occurrences of http://yui.yahooapis.com with https://yui-s.yahooapis.com.

You can see it used in this YUI Library Examples: ProfilerViewer Control.